# SSLHandshakeException while trying to consume REST web service

Tags: rest, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to consume a secured rest endpoint through java code as following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getUrl();
}

private static void getUrl(){
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191\\keystore\\test.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test123");    

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<SignedURL> signedURLEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://tfgts.xyz.com:16610/file-transfer/get-url?fmt=json", SignedURL.class);
    System.out.println("PUT URL : "+signedURLEntity.getBody().getPuturl());
}
```

I have imported the test.jks certificate in the following way

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore .\test.jks -destkeystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

I could find the alias of the certificate I imported, when I ran the below command

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

I'm using eclipse IDE to run this java class and configured the Java build path of the project to the JDK path where the certificate is imported. Also, I ordered the JAVA_HOME in path environment variables to be on top.

But still I'm getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://tfgts.xyz.com:16610/file-transfer/get-url": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:359)
    at com.paychex.retirement.ml.service.SterlingFileProcessor.getUrl(FileProcessor.java:99)
    at com.paychex.retirement.ml.service.SterlingFileProcessor.main(FileProcessor.java:88)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: I think you need to use this as truststore. `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path_to_your_cacerts_file);`

Comment: try enabling SSL debug logs to get more information `java -Djavax.net.debug=all`

Comment: I was able to resolve this exception by copying my company's internal cacerts which has additional certs imported in it.